# Code not working properly - without any errors

Tags: mysql, pyodbc

So I'm intendending to either remove, update or insert a tuple dependening on some circumstances but I cannot get it to work.

First I see if I have any employee with a particular ESSN on a project number by checking:

count = cursor2.execute("SELECT Distinct ESSN FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN = ? AND Pno = ?", (SSN, ProjectNumber)).rowcount

Which I looked up should return -1 if the select did not find any, or if it is unsure how many tuples it found.In my case it returned 0.

However when I do these if - statements:

```
if((ChangeToHours==0) and (count != -1)):

    print "0"

    cursor2.execute("Delete FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN = ? AND Pno = ?", SSN, ProjectNumber) 

    print "Removed %s from project %s" %SSN, ProjectNumber


if((ChangeToHours>0) and (ChangeToHours<=40) and (count != -1)):

    print "!= -1"

    cursor2.execute("Update Hours SET Hours= ? WHERE ESSN=? AND Pno =?", ChangeToHours, SSN, 
ProjectNumber)

    print "Number of hours which employee %s works on project %s successfully changed to %d", SSN, ProjectNunmber,ChangeToHours
```

Using some SSN and project Number and ChangeToHours = 13 as an input I should get into the latter "if" but I get into the first one. Also, my code is not doing anything pass it printing 0, what I can see. At least it doesn't print the "Removed..." text which it should do.

I get no errors what-so-ever running this code.

Anyone have any idea?

Regards,
Cenderze

Comment: Would still greatly appreciate some help (Couldn't find any information regarding bumping your post so I hope this is not unappreciated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself.

Since this was my first laboration using Python I guess I overlooked the basics. ChangedToHours was not made into a float or any other data type which of course causes issues with these comparisons.

So, embarassing fix but might be of use for someone else!

Regards
Cenderze